# Meteor: cannot find property 'event' of undefined in secondary js file

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper

So I'm deving a website with Meteor, I have a basic app set up with a main css, html and js. These files all work fine. I have another html that I'm loading into a div using jquery.load(), and I have another js file associated with that html file -- cm.html and cm.js as shown below.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

     <div id="cm-container">

         {{> addBook}}
        {{> bookshell}}
    </div>
</body>
<template name="bookshell">
 <ul>
  {{#each books}}
   <li>{{subject}}</li>
  {{/each}}
 </ul>
</template>
<template name="addBook">
 <form class="addBookForm">
  <input type="text" class="subject" placeholder="Subject">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">add book</button>
 </form>
</template>
```

and cm.js:

```
books = new Meteor.Collection("books");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

Template.addBook.events({
  'submit .addBookForm' : function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    books.insert({
      subject: template.find(".subject").value,
    });
  }
});

Template.bookshell.books = function () {
    return books.find({}, {sort: {subject: 1}});
    };
}
```

When I load cm.html into my main html file through jquery.load() I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong because the same format in my main js and html work fine.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing `jquery.load()` instead of yielding templates the Meteor way? When you do it through jQuery the `Template.addBook` object probably doesn't get created.

Comment: Hey @fuzzybabybunny I'm open to doing it any way that works, but what I want to happen is when someone clicks a button, this html file gets loaded into an arbitrary div. Can the meteor way accomplish this? and if so how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you achieve this by using Session variables instead of jquery.load().

For example, define a Session variable in your main template that tracks whether the button has been clicked:

main.js

```
Template.main.onRendered(function() {
  Session.set("showForm", false);
});

Template.main.events({
  'click .showForm' : function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var showForm = Session.get("showForm");
      Session.set("showForm", !showForm);
}
})
```

Then you can use that session variable to dynamically hide/show the addBook template:

main.js (or really any client side js file)

```
Template.registerHelper('showForm' function() {
  return Session.get('showForm');
})
```

inside main template:

```
{{#if showForm}}
 {{> addBook}}
{{/if}}
```